# How to use SwiftUI inside Xcode Playground?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground

How to render a SwiftUI view inside Xcode Playground? `PreviewProvider` does not seem to work with Swift Playground.

```
struct FooView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Foo")
    }
}

struct SampleView: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FooView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PlaygroundPage` from `PlaygroundSupport` is what needed to render a SwiftUI view.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct FooView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Foo")
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(FooView())
```

[image]

and as @cbjeukendrup mentioned this also works with [Playgrounds](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/swift-playgrounds/id908519492) on iPadOS.

[image]

Comment: Nice! What's more, this also works on iPad, which is ideal when you quickly want to try something out but don't have your computer with you.